# Help me to better understand the intersection of Sylow $p$-subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Say you have some collection of Sylow $p$-subgroups. For example lets say their are 7 Sylow $3$-subgroups. and that each has order $9$
There are three cases( right ?)

i) any pair $P_1\neq P_2 $ intersect non-trivially

ii) every pair $P_1\neq P_2$ intersect non trivially

iii) every pair of $P_1 \neq P_2$ intersect trivially

My questions:
(Note: trivial intersection then we know that there are 7(9-1)=56 elements of order nine)

a) If we say that any pair $P_1,P_2$ intersect non trivially does this mean that there could be , for instance , just two p-sylow subgroups which intersected non- trivially so they shared three elements one of which was shared by all the other sylow 3 subgroups. like wise we could then have three sylow 3 subgroups which shared 3 elements etc. etc. Is this correct (/ possible in a Sylow p-subgroup ) ?

b) In my notes (regarding showing whether a group was simple) my lecturer didn't consider case two which led me to believe that perhaps case i) and ii) as I have stated them might be in fact the same thing . Is there any merit to this thought ?

c)If all of the P's intersect non trivially then we know that the size of there subgroup is 3 but the number of total elements of order 3,9 is 7(9-3)=42 ( as opposed to the trivial case. see note ). But if cases i) and ii) are in fact distinct then this only works for ii). I don't want the actual equation just to know... is there a similarly simplistic formula as the two i mentioned here, for calculating the number of elements , that can be applied to case i) ( conceptual explanations would be appreciated aswell )

Comment: There certainly aren't precisely 5 3-Sylow subgroups!

Comment: I only chose a random example off the top of my head , I don't know enough about groups to have known that my choice was impossible. what would be a better example and i'll edit it ?

Comment: Just about any number that leaves a remainder of 1 when divided by 3.  For example, 7 would work.

Comment: I don't see any reason why all pairs must intersect nontrivially if one pair does. This seems to be what you are claiming.

Comment: @MattSamuel No I have the case where one or more pairs may intersect non-trivially and the second case where all of them intersect non-trivially . But I meant these as being didtinct scenarios not as one implying the other .

Comment: "any" and "every" mean the same thing here. If you want to say one or more but not necessarily all, use "some" or "at least one."

Comment: @MattSamuel Ah perhaps this is the source of my misunderstanding. Can you answer me this though is their a case where every group just intersects at identity, one where every group intersects for a set but then a third case where we could some of the groups intersect trivially and others do not ( some pairs perhaps even having different sized intersections than others ) ?

Comment: @exo If some pair intersects nontrivially, then every Sylow subgroup of that order intersects with some other Sylow subgroup having an intersection of the same size. But I would imagine it's possible that some pairs intersect trivially while others do not, and some nontrivial intersections can have different sizes than others. This is not my area of specialty so I don't have any examples.